# Grouping an Integer List into Partitions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Is there a easy way to do following in a stream:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
    System.out.print(partitioningValues(integerList, 3));
}

private static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> partitioningValues(List<Integer> integerList, int numberOfPartitions) {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> integerListMap = new HashMap<>();
    BigDecimal limit = BigDecimal.valueOf(integerList.size() / (double) numberOfPartitions);
    int limitRounded = limit.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).intValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPartitions; i++) {

        int toIndex = ((i + 1) * limitRounded) > integerList.size() ? integerList.size() : (i + 1) * limitRounded;
        integerListMap.put(i, integerList.subList(i * limitRounded, toIndex));
    }

    return integerListMap;
}
```

**Result:**

> {0=[1, 2, 3, 4], 1=[5, 6, 7, 8], 2=[9, 10]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `groupingBy` to split.

If the stream needs to be split by elements value

```
int split = 4;
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map2 = integerList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> (i-1) / split));
System.out.println(map2);
```

If the stream needs to be split by position

```
int[] pos = { -1 };
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = integerList.stream().peek(e -> pos[0]++).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> pos[0] / split));
System.out.println(map);
```

output

```
{0=[1, 2, 3, 4], 1=[5, 6, 7, 8], 2=[9, 10]}
```

Comment: first solution does not split the original List.

Comment: yeah, missed `map`

Comment: Sorry my friend but no one of this represent a solution.. Try with another input: `List<Integer> integerList = Arrays.asList(10, 22, 23, 4, 25, 6, 27, 8, 9, 10);`

Comment: `{0=[10, 22, 23, 4], 1=[25, 6, 27, 8], 2=[9, 10]}` from the second solution, I added description in the answers

Comment: also the Question does not mention how to split the stream, by value or index, that's why added both the solution, BTW in second solution, am having a object array to keep the index but that's a bad practice should be avoided, wont work in parallel stream

Comment: ok, second solution worked but with some little changes: `int[]split =new int[]{4};` 
  `Map<Object, List<Integer>> map = integerList.stream().peek(e -> pos[0]++).peek(System.out::println)
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> pos[0] / split[0]));`

Answer (score 0):

I propose you this approach: it iterates from `0` to `numberOfPartitions`, at each step it creates a sublist of `batchLength` elements (only the last step could have less then `batchLength` elements) and collects the sublists in a `HashMap` where the key is the current step and the value is the sublist at current step.

```
public static Map<Integer, List<Integer>> partitioningValues(List<Integer> integerList, int numberOfPartitions) {
    int size = integerList.size();
    BigDecimal limit = BigDecimal.valueOf(size / (double) numberOfPartitions);
    int batchLength =  limit.setScale(0, BigDecimal.ROUND_UP).intValue();
    AtomicInteger step = new AtomicInteger();
    return IntStream.range(0, numberOfPartitions)
            .boxed()
              .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                   s -> step.getAndIncrement(), 
                   s -> integerList.subList(s * batchLength, Math.min((s+1)*batchLength, size)))
              );
}
```

Grouping by version (very similar to second solution of @Saravana):

```
...
AtomicInteger pos =  new AtomicInteger(0);
AtomicInteger split = new AtomicInteger(batchLength);
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = integerList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> Integer.valueOf(pos.getAndIncrement() / split.get())));
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to mutate a shared variable to keep track of the indexes and want to keep the stream parallellizable, you can still do so by using an alternative strategy.**

The partition size is the maximum number of integers in a single partition. In all code snippets, let us define `partitionSize` as follows:

```
int partitionSize = (list.size() - 1) / partitions + 1;
```

where we use the concise -1/+1 notation for ceiling instead of `Math.ceil`.

**A simple naive approach** would be to find the index to group by:

```
list.stream().collect(groupingBy(i -> list.indexOf(i) / partitionSize));
```

But if you care about performance, you want to find a better way to handle the indexes.

**An intuitive approach** could be to first generate all the index positions, then iterate over them and collect the sublists. This would give you something like this, combining all the partitions in a `List<List<Integer>>`:

```
int[] indexes = IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + partitionSize).limit(partitions+1).toArray();

IntStream.range(0, indexes.length - 1)
         .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(indexes[i], Math.min(indexes[i + 1], list.size())))
         .collect(toList());
```

Where `Math.min` is used to find the correct end boundaries of the interval in case we approach the end of the list.

**You can however combine the index calculation and the looping** as follows:

```
  IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() / partitionSize)
           .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * partitionSize, Math.min((i+1) * partitionSize, list.size())))
           .collect(toList());
```

Remark that the result is a `List<List<Integer>>` where every list index maps on the sublist of the partition.

**If you really want a map** with keys 0,1,2,... you could collect to a Map instead:

```
Map<Integer, List<List<Integer>>> result =
      IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() / partitionSize)
               .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * partitionSize, Math.min((i + 1) * partitionSize, list.size())))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(l -> l.get(0) / partitionSize));
```

**Or, if you don't mind using external libraries**, e.g. Guava has

```
Lists.partition(integerList, 3);
```

> **Example.**
>
> ```
> List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
>
> int partitions = 4;
> int partitionSize = (list.size() - 1) / partitions + 1; //ceil
>
> List<List<Integer>> result = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, list.size() / partitionSize)
>                                       .mapToObj(i -> list.subList(i * partitionSize, Math.min((i+1) * partitionSize, list.size())))
>                                       .collect(toList());
>
> System.out.println(result);
> ```
>
> **Result**: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10]]